# Regular Expression - How to invert into NOT

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which I can chain a few not rules together. I need to validate a number string to check that it does NOT match a few rules.

I need it to:

1. Not start with 3 zeroes
2. Not end with 4 zeroes
3. Not be all the same digit

Here is what I'm trying so far:

```
var re = new RegExp(/^(.)\1{8}$|^000|0000$/);

re.test("111111111"); // true; all same digit
re.test("000112222"); // true; starts with zeroes
re.test("111110000"); // true; ends in zeroes
re.test("123456789"); // false
re.test("111223344"); // false
```

This works for the first three cases by yielding TRUE, how can I invert the test to have it be false unless it meets the 3 rules?

(I know I can just flip it in the JS with a `!`, I'm looking for a regex solution)

Comment: Don't delimiter when you use constructor. `new RegExp('...')` or `/.../`

Comment: You can use a *negative lookahead*.

Comment: @Toto, can you explain why?

Comment: Because it is said in the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting all rules together, you can use this regex:

```
/^(?!0{3})(?!.*0{4}$)(\d)(?!\1*$)\d*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYN7fU/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^           # start
(?!0{3})    # negative lookahead to assert failure when we have 3 0s at start
(?!.*0{4}$) # negative lookahead to assert failure when we have 4 0s at end
(\d)        # match a digit and capture in group #1
(?!\1*$)    # negative lookahead to assert we don't have same digit until end 
\d*         # match zero or more digits
$           # end
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining what the different parts are.

Comment: What do you think all those proponents are readable code say everything they hear the term "regular expression"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you @Adam

Comment: Just rambling commentary, your solution is great.